# Does UISearchContainerViewController work on iOS

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

UISearchContainerViewController exists both on tvOS and on iOS.

Apple has sample code showing how to use it in **tvOS**: they configure a UISearchController, hand it to a UISearchContainerViewController, wrap that in a UINavigationController, and make it one of a UITabBarController's children.

But I have never seen an example of UISearchContainerViewController on **iOS**, and I can't make it work there. For example, I do exactly what Apple does, except that I push the UISearchContainerViewController onto a navigation stack, or I wrap it in a navigation controller and present it, or whatever; and there's no search field so the whole thing is useless.

Has anyone ever gotten UISearchContainerViewController to do anything useful on iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for answer to the same question. But I got this working like that :

**Base VC**

```
    let vc = SearchContainerVC()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**SearchContainerVC**

```
class SearchContainerVC: UISearchContainerViewController {

    init() {
        let searchResultsTableVC = SearchResultsTableViewController()
        let searchVC = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsTableVC)
        searchVC.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchVC.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchVC.searchBar.delegate = searchResultsTableVC
        searchVC.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsTableVC

        let searchBar = searchVC.searchBar
        searchBar.delegate = searchResultsTableVC
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for something"

        searchVC.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchVC.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        super.init(searchController: searchVC)

        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    }
}
```

**SearchResultsTableViewController**

```
class SearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // I use a Table to show search items
}
```

Comment: But when I do that (1) it looks terrible and (2) there is no coherent way to dismiss it. Notice also that Apple's tvOS example does _not_ put the search bar into the interface; it all just seems to happen by magic. I can't help feeling that that _should_ happen on iOS too, and it doesn't because we're not supposed to use UISearchContainerViewController at all.

Comment: OK, I was able to get this to look acceptable by (1) setting the UISearchContainerViewController's view's background color to white, and (2) setting the search bar's `showsCancelButton` to true so that it doesn't suddenly appear. Also, I used the new `navigationItem.searchController` feature.

Comment: Good to hear that you've figured it out, @matt !

Comment: Yes, at first I was skeptical; I thought you weren't doing anything that we couldn't do _without_ a UISearchContainerViewController. I thought we could just do this with an ordinary container view controller. But that seems not to be the case. The UISearchContainerViewController is doing _something_ for us, though I'm a little unclear what it is.

Comment: Yeah, it does. For example if I do it without UISearchContainerViewController, I get the 'presenting on modal' error when typing on the search field (just when empty table (searchResultsController) should show up) :D